# Hide Transform Widgets Display Panel

Tags: python, 3d-view, transforms, panel

[image]

Greetings. Is there a way to hide this Transform Widgets Display Panel within the 3D Viewport, using python or otherwise? Also get it to stretch along it's width wider than it will go? I have multiple 3D viewports I'm using (in different tabs), so I only want it hidden in one of them. Also, I have a custom panel underneath it, I would like that to stay visible. Blender 2.83.3

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>T</kbd> and it should go away.

Comment: T hides it, as well as the custom Panel that I made, which I don't want. I'm looking to do it in Python

Comment: @Increality Sorry, I don't know anything about python.

Comment: @Increality, or at least not how to code in it!